# Count if a date exists between a date range and if checkboxes are true

Tags: google-sheets, countif, date-range

I'm trying to find a method in Google sheets to return a value in a cell that tells my team the available number of slots. The value counts the date if it's between a date range.

For example, I have two columns - 'Start date' (column A) and 'End date' (column B).

```
| Start date  |   End date |
| --------    |   -------- |
| 23/04/2023  | 25/04/2023 |
| 23/04/2023  | 24/04/2023 |
| 27/05/2023  | 30/04/2023 |
```

Based on the dates, it would count/return the values below:

```
23/04/2023 = 2
24/04/2023 = 2
25/04/2023 = 1
26/04/2023 = 0
27/04/2023 = 1
28/04/2023 = 1
29/04/2023 = 1
30/04/2023 = 1`
```

However, I want to introduce another condition where it counts only if a checkbox column is true.

So far, I can only manage to find the solution on counting if date is between range.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Q2KOFTP9JCxxoIhf0Yj_zjJDWYwg1KGbDhLiNxd0d6g/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 0):

Ashley,

This can be done using my custom function that simulates SQL SELECT syntax.

- The function in your sheet would be something like:

```
=gsSQL("select (select count(*) from log where avail.date >= log.start_date and avail.date <= log.end_date and banner = 1) as slots from avail", {{"log", "gsSqlTest!E206:H210", 0}; {"avail", "gsSqlTest!A206:A211", 0}}, true)
```

- In the gsSQL() custom function, it is defining the tables used between the curly braces.  This can be omitted when the entire SHEET TAB name defines the table.  So 'Advertising Log' TAB could be used in the SQL as **advertising_log**.
- I have used **banner** as a flag, but I am not sure what checkbox you were trying to use.  You can adjust the SQL SELECT statement to check any column (a CHECKED box is equal to 1 in my SELECT). The UNIQUE column title must be specified, which is used as the field name in the select.
- You would need the custom function added to your Apps Script.  The source code is here:
  https://github.com/demmings/gsSQL/blob/main/dist/gssql.js
- Notes for using is here:
  https://github.com/demmings/gsSQL
- My notes for using a correlated sub-query are here:
  https://demmings.github.io/new%20feature/2022/12/23/Correlated-Sub-Query.html
- My test google sheet is here.  See line 206
  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Zmyk7a7u0xvICrxen-c0CdpssrLTkHwYx6XL00Tb1ws/edit?usp=sharing
  [image]

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for this.

I copied your test google sheet and after running the script, it doesn't seem to change anything (for example. I unchecked the boxes in column H but the values in column B (B207 - B210) did not change.

Comment: Did you get the custom function ?  It requires a custom function also, which would not be copied if you did a copy/paste of the cells.

Comment: One other thing I forgot.  Custom functions are only re-executed when the sheet is loaded or data in the function parameter changes.  What I do if I need to force a re-execute is to add a last parameter that is linked to a check-box.  Toggling the check box will force a re-execute.

Comment: Ashley.  I updated my custom function so that it automatically triggers to run if any data in source tables changes.  The function would be written as:  =gsSQL("select (select count(*) from log where avail.date >= log.start_date and avail.date <= log.end_date and banner = 1) as slots from avail", "log", gsSqlTest!E206:H210, "avail", gsSqlTest!A206:A211, true)

Comment: Hi Chris, this works, thanks so much! If I wanted it to count based on the checkbox of two columns, how would I go about that?

Answer (score 0):

- The column title is used as the field name.  If you specify the sheet range to include any required check boxes, you should be able to just modify the WHERE logic.
- In this example, the **banner** column is the check box and the SQL **banner = 1** sees if the box was checked.
- To add another checkbox comparison, just add your condition like **and banner = 1 and someOtherBox = 1)** - so both MUST be true to be included.
- If either can be checked to be included, use the **OR** condition instead.

```
=gsSQL("select (select count(*) from log where avail.date >= log.start_date and avail.date <= log.end_date and banner = 1 and someOtherBox = 1) as slots from avail", "log", gsSqlTest!E206:H210, "avail", gsSqlTest!A206:A211, true)
```